# What does a fully enabled GPU mean?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

As the title says, what is a fully enabled GPU?

> AMD pulled out all the stops on the RX 6900 XT. It has a fully enabled
> Navi 21 GPU, which helps account for its scarcity.

source: https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/best-gpus,4380.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silicon is prone to defects which means that areas of circuitry sometimes does not work as intended. Either they don't work well at high speeds, in which case a manufacturer will clock them down, or entire sections will simply not work at all.

GPUs though have an upside. They are essentially a large set of repeated circuits and a failure in one set does not render the entire unit useless. That failed section, so long as it is not a critical area, can simply be disabled and rendered useless.

Perfect silicon will have all sections and cores usable with no disabled sections.

Imperfect silicon will have one or more cores disabled, the more cores disabled the lower the part ends up in the range.

Basically the manufacturer will make one intended part and then "bin" each part according to what clock speeds it can manage or how many cores have to be disabled. This simplifies manufacturing and reduces waste, while maximising profits.

Comment: Fun Fact: Silicon wafers are circle and processors are square.  So the same silicone wafer ends up being multiple products because of those imperfections.  Often a cheaper product, with small differences (10 GB VRAM instead of 12 GB) but uses the same IC will be created to use those imperfect ICs.  Individuals have modified what are essential identical products themselves either by adding the VRAM to the board because the traces (but the memory IC doesn’t) still exists or by modifying the firmware to essentially unlock existing but unstable feature

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the accepted answer is, in this case, **wrong**.
There is nothing wrong with the answer in general, but in this case it doesn't apply.

The linked article places this in the context of GPU's that have artifical restrictions to make them less attractive for crypto-currency mining.
NVidia and AMD have done this to several high-end GPU's because the crypto-guys were buying every GPU they could find which made high-end GPU's even more scarce than they already were and which greatly inflated prices.
(These restrictions don't affect the use of these cards for gaming.)

This RX6900XT has no such restrictions and is therefore more attractive (and thus scarce due to high demand).

Comment: I hadn't read the article that way. I wouldn't say my answer is wrong so much as incomplete. A GPU that is "fully enabled" in terms of all the compute units being available is not mutually exclusive with there being limiters and silicon with more compute blocks would still be more attractive than a unit with less. Surely a better word they would have used if they had meant it had no limiters would be "unlimited". Using "fully enabled" in regard to limiters being disabled makes little linguistic sense to me.

Comment: @Mokubai I agree. The 2 concepts complement each other. And the wording in the article is really vague.